# Return BIRT calculated report values back to custom web application for further processing

Tags: eclipse, web-services, reporting, birt

I'd like to run a report in a custom application (no birt viewer, direct integration of the report engine in the application code for rendering reports under the hood and providing links to the final documents).

After rendering the report I need to read back specific values which were calculated in the report - e.g. for pushing it towards a webservice of a different application.

Imagine an invoice report with master and details which calculates in the master section then the aggregated payment sum of all invoice details. If I would need to pass the calculated payment sum to a payment service from the appplication (not in the report!) - how would I do that ?

- I've seen DataExtractionTasks in the Birt API. However they seem to be heavily query-related in the rare examples I found and I am not sure if they would somehow work with non-resultset data as well.
- I tried to use GlobalPersistentReportVariables and access them after rendering the report via the API - however via the API they always seem to be null. Not sure if this is the "right way" to access calculated report values. I think they are mainly provided for sharing data in between different report elements like tables.

I certainly do not want to duplicate the report logic in the application just to calculate the payment sum again.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that in theory the DataExtraction task would be the right thing I couldn't get a simple report element's (e.g. dynamic text element) value for publishing it somewhere else.

I have it working now by abusing the holy appContext (general-purpose-throw-in-anything thing) for getting the required data back into my application (report writes calculated value into the appcontext - application reads in after rendering the report).

Comment: Using the appContext is the recommended and by far easiest solution here. We are doing it the same way. Another option would be to pass an application-specific context object and use this as a report parameter, but this will make it more difficult to develop the report in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

First is the integration --> http://wiki.eclipse.org/Birt_3.7_Migration_Guide

Secondly you have to create a custom XML plugins for BIRT.

added that plugin into ur integrate BIRT.

Now render ur report in XML format(Remember the XML format will defined in ur plugin, so give such format that u can read it easily with any javascript,jquery or Java file only )

Now do any calculation/manipulation u like.

In my case, i was having 2 context file i.e.

Context-1(Myapplication.war)--calling-->> Context-2(BIRT.war with customized XML plugin)

I called BIRT report using javascript XMLRequest method with 
URL: "http://localhost:8080/birt/framset?_*report=GraphReport1.rptdesign&*_format=xml"

And the reading xml format in javascript & showing the customized jquery graphs according to data.

Comment: As I've stated in the question I don't require the Birt Viewer (war) at all - not technically and not from the requirements. SO going through the web layer is in any case not necessary. The engine works fine without the Birt Viewer and renders PDF/Excel while being 100% in my own web application.

Comment: Yes, that option is also there. totally depend upon ur requirement.